# I am getting an error when trying to hookup my backend. it says errno: -4078

Tags: node.js, postgresql

here is the error:

```
  original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1148:16) {
    errno: -4078,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 5000
  }
}
```

```
require('dotenv').config()

const express = require('express')
const sequelize = require('./db')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

const app = express()

const start = async () => {
    try{
        await sequelize.authenticate()
        await sequelize.sync()
        app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`))
    } catch (e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}

start().then()
```

here's my database file

```
require('dotenv').config()
const {Sequelize} = require('sequelize')


module.exports = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DB_NAME,
    process.env.DB_USER,
    process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    {
        dialect: 'postgres',
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: process.env.PORT
    }
)
```

I am using postgres as my server and I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I don't know if it is the authentication or of it is simply not able to find the server as in it's looking at the wrong port. I have my DB_PORT set to 5432 so I don't think that is the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your port to 5432 directly

```
{
    dialect: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: 5432
   }
```

process.env.PORT refers only to your port of theWebapplikation
}